# How do you run a DART application as a windows service?

Tags: windows-services, dart

I've been researching the possibility of using the DART language for my next project. The only thing really holding me back at this point is that I'm unable to find a way to run a DART application as a windows service. I have run searches on Google and read through much of the documentation on the DART website. Most of the information I found was related to creating a server in DART but nothing regarding windows services.

Can someone either point me at directions or detail the steps necessary to do so?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's the problem? You can create a service for your dart script, just as you would for every other executable, can't you?

Comment: I've actually never done that for anything on Windows besides something in C# .Net using Visual Studio. Do you perhaps have directions for doing this for any generic script?

Comment: [sc.exe create](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192/en) should do the trick. The executable is dart.exe, and the path to your dart file is the parameter - you may need to add the parameter manually in services.msc after creating it.

Comment: @user1125786 did you succeed? If so can you tell me how? Because when I try to start it, it repsonse with an error `The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

Comment: I got pulled into something else and haven't had a chance to try it yet. Once I do I'll post the results here.

Answer (score 6):

=== Latest Update ===

My original answer consisted of using C and Dart FFI to boostrap the Windows Service. However, none of this is really needed as a much, much, simpler solution can be had by using Docker with Windows Containers.

Instead of actually running the application as a Windows Service, the alternative is to compile it to an executable Windows console application, create a Docker file and a Windows Docker image that will include that application. On the server you will need docker and you can simply run the image with a --restart option. To test this out, Windows 10 supports Docker with Windows containers.

So, the simple solution is, we don't really need to run Dart code as a Windows Service, because we can run it as a docker container on the server.

=== Original Answer ===

I am arriving really late to the game, but I figured a way around this problem without having to use 3rd party applications.

My solution is kind of an hack, but hey, it works. I am compiling the dart application as an executable and then registering it as a Windows Service, using sc.exe create. The issue with sc.exe create is that the main function of the application needs to perform some extra steps to inform Windows that it is running. If this isn't done, Windows service gets stuck in a "Starting state".

I don't think there is a pub package available to perform this duty. However, there are 2 things we can use: Dart:FFI, and the following article from Mohit Arora that explains how to create a Windows Service in C++. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499465/Simple-Windows-Service-in-Cplusplus

I grabbed Mohit's code and made a ton of changes (including backporting it to C, because... C++)

### C

Here's the full code of the Service.c file:

```
// Provides an API for Dart console applications to
// integrate themselves as Windows Services
// The entry point to this API is the Init(...)
// function at the bottom of this file.

// The Init(...) function registers the ServiceMain(...)
// function as the actual windows service function.
// the ServiceMain function does the following:
//
// 1. Registers the ServiceCtrlHandler(...) function 
// as the service control handler, which is essentially
// tasked to handle control requests (in this case we 
// are only handling the request to stop the service).
//
// 2. Creates an event object that and then waits indefinitely 
// for the event to be set.
//
// The ServiceCtrlHandler(...) function responds to a
// close request by setting the event created by the 
// ServiceMain(...) function, essentially freeing 
// the latter from the indefinite wait and terminating
// it.

// The functions in this file don't actually 
// do any work, but keep the Windows Service
// alive. The work be initiated by the calling 
// application either before or after the call to Init(...).

// Because this was developed for the purpose
// of enabling Dart applications to run as 
// Windows Services, it it the Dart Application 
// that needs to call Init(...) using Dart FFI.
// It must also be the Dart Application to 
// spawn an isolate that does the actual work
// before the call to Init(...)

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "service.h"


SERVICE_STATUS        g_ServiceStatus = { 0 };
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE g_StatusHandle = NULL;
HANDLE                g_ServiceStopEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


LPWSTR w_service_name;


void UpdateStatus(
    DWORD newState,
    DWORD checkPoint,
    DWORD exitCode,
    DWORD controlsAccepted)
{
    g_ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = controlsAccepted;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = newState;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = exitCode;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint = checkPoint;

    SetServiceStatus(g_StatusHandle, &g_ServiceStatus);
}


// Responds to control events. This implementation is
// only responding to the SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP event
// This method signals the ServiceMain function
// that it can stop waiting before terminating.
void WINAPI ServiceCtrlHandler(DWORD CtrlCode)
{
    if (CtrlCode != SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP || g_ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_RUNNING)
        return;

    UpdateStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, 4, 0, 0);

    SetEvent(g_ServiceStopEvent);

}


void InitServiceStatus()
{
    ZeroMemory(&g_ServiceStatus, sizeof(g_ServiceStatus));
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    g_ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    UpdateStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING, 0, 0, 0);
}


// This function essentially creates an event object 
// and enters a holding pattern until that event object 
// is set by the ServiceCtrlHandler(...) in response
// to a close request.

// The function doesn't actually do any work,
// except to keep the Windows Service alive.
void WINAPI ServiceMain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv)
{
    g_StatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(w_service_name, ServiceCtrlHandler);

    if (g_StatusHandle == NULL)
        return;

    InitServiceStatus();

    g_ServiceStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

    if (g_ServiceStopEvent == NULL)
    {
        UpdateStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED, 1, GetLastError(), 0);
        return;
    }

    UpdateStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING, 0, 0, SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(g_ServiceStopEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        ;

    CloseHandle(g_ServiceStopEvent);
    UpdateStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED, 3, 0, 0);
}



LPWSTR get_service_name(const char* service_name)
{
    int max_count = strlen(service_name);
    int size = max_count + 1;
    LPWSTR ret = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * size);
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, ret, size, service_name, max_count);
    return ret;
}



/// This is the entry point that should be called
/// by the Dart application (or any application 
/// of a similar kind of platform) in order to 
/// integrate itself as a Windows Service.
/// It registers the ServiceMain(...) function
/// as the service main function. Please consult
/// the comments at that function to understand
/// what it does.
int init(const char* service_name)
{
    w_service_name = get_service_name(service_name);

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[] =
    {
        {w_service_name, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    if (StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable) == FALSE)
        return GetLastError();
}
```

The Service.h header file is, naturally, a lot smaller:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef WINSERVICE_EXPORTS
#define WINSERVICE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WINSERVICE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


WINSERVICE_API int init(const char* service_name);
```

Just make sure you add WINSERVICE_EXPORTS to one of the definitions or replace it by the corresponding definition in your project.

### Dart

I also needed to perform a few changes from the Dart side. Here's my prototype:

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart' as grpc;

// These two types represent the
// Init(...) function of the C API
typedef init_func = ffi.Int32 Function(ffi.Pointer<Utf8>);
typedef Init = int Function(ffi.Pointer<Utf8>);

// Entry point to the Dart application.
// When run as a Windows Service,
// this is still the entry point.
// This code is not embeded but is started
// as a regular console application.
void main() async {
  final init = createInit();

  // Starts the actual work in a separate Isolate
  await Isolate.spawn(run, 'message');

  final serviceName = Utf8.toUtf8('MProto_Server_from_Dart');
  // calls the Init(...) function
  var result = init(serviceName);
  if (result != 0) return;

  // blocks this Isolate indefinitely from continuing
  while (true) {
    sleep(Duration(days: 365));
  }
}

// Creates the instance of the proxy to the Init(...)
// function.
Init createInit() {
  final path =
      r'[PATH to the C compiled DLL]';
  final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(path);

  // ignore: omit_local_variable_types
  final Init init =
      dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<init_func>>('init').asFunction();
  return init;
}


// Performs the actual work that needs to
// be done, in this case, we are hosting
// a gRPC service, but this should 
// work with any other kind of 
// payload, namely other types of
// http services.
void run(String message) async {
  print('inside isolate');
  var server = grpc.Server(
    [
// my service classes
    ],
  );
  await server.serve(port: 5001);
}
```

Comment: im very interested in your "old" solution, since im trying to deploy a dart executable as a service on a clients machine. and since its a clients machine, i cant rly use any 3rd party tools or setup docker containers. sadly though, your code does not quite work for me, the service init function fails with code 1063 and i have not rly an idea why (ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT) ...

Comment: @rui-craveiro your "old" solution is the natural and more elegant solution as it follows the traditional way of deploying application on windows. The Dart EXE and the DLL created from your old solution can simply be copied to any directory or packaged and deployed using any installer. It will just work.

Furthermore, you only need to compile the DLL once and you can package it with unlimited Dart applications you want to run as windows service.

Based on the above, I will recommend your "old" solution.

Thank you.

Comment: @rui-craveiro do you have an idea why result in the line below will return 1, instead of 0.

```var result = init(serviceName);
  if (result != 0) return;```

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in using Dart for a Windows service as any other executable; you just need to call dart.exe with the correct arguments.

However, Windows doesn't support running arbitrary exes as Windows Services, as they require a little metadata/bootstrapping. I've had good experiences with [NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/). In the comments, SC.exe was suggested; but I was unable to get it running on the latest version of Windows Server :(

Answer (score 2):

look at dart package `dart_windows_service_support`

He use `dart:ffi` and a `dll` file enables dart to run in Windows service mode

https://pub.dev/packages/dart_windows_service_support

Answer (score 0):

Use [WinSW](https://github.com/winsw/winsw)

> WinSW wraps and manages any application as a Windows service.

1. Create the `service` directory in your project.
2. Find the latest [release of WinSW](https://github.com/winsw/winsw/releases) on GitHub, you are very likely looking specifically for WinSW-x64.exe. Copy this file under the `service` directory in your project and rename it to your linking, e.g. `service\MyApp-Service.exe`.
3. Create a configuration file for your service `service\MyApp-Service.xml` with the sample configuration below.
4. Run `.\MyApp-Service.exe install` from command line. Your service should be listed in Windows services.

Sample config XML:

```xml
<service>
  <id>MyApp</id>
  <name>My App</name>
  <description>My App's description</description>
  <executable>C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe</executable>
  <workingdirectory>C:\path\to\project</workingdirectory>
  <arguments>lib/main.dart</arguments>
  <log mode="roll"></log>
  <priority>high</priority>
</service>
```