# AutoRestart crashed DART lang server app

Tags: dart

If for any reason my the DART app stopped or crashed, due to illegal operation or something else, is there away to restart it automatically, or I've to restart it manually using "dart app.dart" command?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways. It depends on your requirements.

- Run the Dart app as a Windows service
  [How do you run a DART application as a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056419)
  http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunDartScriptAsAService.html
- Use a bash script which restarts the app immediately after it exits

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  echo "start app"
  /usr/bin/dart bin/server.dart
done
```

- Use a Dart script which does the same using `Process.start()` (from `dart:io`).

and probably many others.

Comment: Thanks, I'm newbie to linux bash script, let me see where shall I save this code, and feedback you if worked fine :)

Comment: Save it in a file `somename.sh`. Run `chmod ug+x somename.sh` (to make it executable for user and group). Save it in a directory which is included in the `PATH` (`echo $PATH`) or create a symlink in a directory which is included in the `PATH`.